# why we are using $(document) instead of $("document") in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

in Jquery,

to select a div, we use `$("div")`. `div` is enclosed with quote symbols.

but why we are always using `$(document)` instead of `$("document")`?.

what is the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there is no such element with **tag name** `document`, i.e. `<document>`. `document` is actually [a *global variable* referring to the current HTML document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document).

The `jQuery` function does not only accept selectors, it also accepts **DOM elements** and **HTML strings**. For example, inside event handlers, [`this` refers to the DOM element the handler was bound to](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/) and that's why you pass the element directly to jQuery (`$(this)`) and not a string (`$("this")`, which would mean something else entirely).

For more information, have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Answer (score 1):

`$("document")` looks for an element with tagName `document` - there is no element with that tagName

where as $(document) creates a wrapper for the root dom object - jQuery takes a dom element reference as the argument

Answer (score 1):

`document` is a [JavaScript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) always available in the page:

> Each web page loaded in the browser has its own document object.

You can wrap this object into JQuery. Using `$("document")` would select an element with tag `document` which cannot exist with standard HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are no tagnames called document in the markup like this

```
<document></document>
```

but there are divs like this

```
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... have *you* ever written `<document>` in your HTML?

`document` is a property of `window` that refers to the current document.

Answer (score 0):

Because `document` is a JS object (property of `window`) referring to the current document, I'm sure you already find this piece of code :

```
window.document
```

And by adding `$()` you extend the document object with all jQuery attributes and methods...